# How to configure a navigation controller in interface builder?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

*I have a navigation controller embedded inside a tab bar controller.*

In the highest level of my navigation ("Root view controller" on the screenshot) I will show categories, but then when the user taps on one category, what the next view controller the navigation controller will display might vary in function of the selected category (especially what's contained by the rows).
I don't know that much how to deal with that, how can I link several view controllers to my navigation controller, and then programmatically show the ones that I need ?
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show different different view controller  on each different cell in tableView in ur case ie. category.  Add view controllers in Your story board.
Add add segue to each controller from table view. not from cell. set identifier to each segue .
After this u can call like this

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", sender: self)
```